# postgresql consumed 100% of storage

Tags: postgresql

I'm running a Red Hat 4.8.3-9 server in AWS cloud with version 9.4 of Postgresql. The database has consumed 100% of my disk usage. I went in to the database and truncated the table with the most data. After viewing the size of the tables with `\d+`, there was not any tables over a couple MB's. I ran `du -h * --max-depth=1` and found that `/var/lib/pgsql94/data/base/16384` held 472G of the 500G total storage. Even after truncating the tables, my disk usage is still 99%. I'm wondering if there is a solution to release the data because I believe deleting all the OID's in `'data/base/16384` would be bad. I have tried stopping, restarting postgres service. I am not allowed to reboot the machine unfortunately.

`df -ih`  shows inode usage is 1%

`sudo lsof +L1` does not show any large files at all

Thank you

Log files: 8K worth of repeating string

> LOG:  could not write temporary statistics file
>   "pg_stat_tmp/db_16384.tmp": No space left on device
>   LOG:  could not
>   close temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/db_0.tmp": No space left
>   on device
>   LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file
>   "pg_stat_tmp/global.tmp": No space left on device
>   LOG:  using stale
>   statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not
>   responding

Comment: Did you try [**Disk Usage**](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Disk_Usage)

Comment: sorry, yes. pg_size_pretty returned the database with '320MB'

Comment: That doesnt make sense. Maybe there are log files?

Comment: I've never seen this log output before but here it is...                                  LOG: could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global/tmp": No space left on device

Comment: Most likely you have a "idle in transaction" somewhere holding onto old tuples that can't be released until it's rolled back or committed. Any idle in transactions in pg_stat_activity?

Comment: anyone got answer to this?

Comment: Got other databases in this postgres instance? Please double check. And... did you use the "large objects" feature? Do you have tons of WAL files hanging around?

Comment: Can you use "du" to find which directory the GBytes are in, then look if that corresponds to an OID in postgres?